# UISegmentedControl Color in ios 7 showing black

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a pretty simple looking problem though I coudn't fix it. I have a UiSegmentedControl and until ios 7 came it worked fine having an ocean color tint.  When I made a UI change in the nib file that contains the segmented control and built it, the selected segment shows black color. I have another nib file that contains segmented control. I didn't touch that file and segmented control appears as old ios 6 styled ocean ine as before ehn I run app on ios 7. Any ideas why it is showing black tint??

Also, I have a sample project in which UISegmentedControl works as expected. So is there any Application Level setting that is overriding color or ignoring color set operation?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you setting the Tint in Storyboard or code? Did you try doing both?

Comment: I am not using storyboard. I tried to set in nib file  and code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an application designed to be compatible with iOS6 but being tested on an iOS7 device.

My UISegmentedControl was displayed in the correct color on the simulator, but was appearing black on the real device, and all UISegmented controls on the pages were impacted.

I just added the following line in the viewDidLoad method after reading the UI recommendation document from Apple, and it solved the problem on the real device :

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

To be honnest, I have absolutely no explanation why it's working... but it's working here.